# Start 5th tabbar view on initial start-up

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, tabbarcontroller

My application uses a tab bar controller. My 5th tab is my settings view controller. I want the user during his or her first start-up ever of the app to start on this tab. Does the tab bar controller have a function to display another tab view other then the first? How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the `setSelectedIndex:` method of the `UITabbarController`.

Eg:

*Considering that your TabBarController object is named aTabbarController*

```
[aTabbarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

---

Now coming to the First Launch Ever,
If you want the user to be navigated only during the First Launch and never again,

Use the `registerDefaults:` method of the `NSUserDefaults`

Eg:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"FirstLaunch"]];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
    [aTabbarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: How would I rewrite that so I can use it as a global variable?

Comment: Not sure what you wanted. Did you want the Key Name `@"FirstLaunch"` to be Global? If so, its very simple, Declare it as a Macro. Eg: After the import lines in your AppDelegate or in the AppName-Prefix.pch file, declare `#define FIRST_LAUNCH @"FirstLaunch"` ... Now you can use `FIRST_LAUNCH` instead of `@"FirstLaunch"`. Eg: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:FIRST_LAUNCH];`